# How to replace this backslash \x character in python?

Tags: python, unicode

```
In [64]: s = "2016\2018"                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [65]: s                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[65]: '2016\x818'

In [66]: s = s.replace("\\", "'\\'")                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [67]: s                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[67]: '2016\x818'
```

I want to use replace it with a single quoted backslash:
But it failed.

Comment: this slash may not exist in string and only Python use it to show code of unicode char instead of original char.

Comment: if you want real \ in text then you have to use `s = "2016\\2018"`. If you don't use  double \\ then Python will not treat \ as char but it will parse `\2018` as code of unicode char. And it will keep it in memory as integer value 2018 without \ and it will add \ only when you try to display it but your console doesn't know how to display this unicode char.

Comment: That's my original text I got from my text file. How to replace it? I can't manually change the text file.

Comment: how do you read it ? It should rather put correct \ when it read it.

Comment: It reads like this in csv file: "2016\2018"

Comment: I can get this problem only if I use `open(..., encoding='unicode_escape')` but if I open normally `open(...)` or use `utf-8` - `open(..., encoding='utf-8')` then a get correct text - Python 3.7

Comment: you should rather show code which you use to read it. At this moment it looks like [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - you try to replace \ to resolve problem but you real problem is to read it correctly without converting \20 to unicode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is escape character therefore you should add `\` after `\` to avoid errors:

`s.replace('\\', "'\\'")`

Also your string should include second `\`, for example:
`2016\\2018`. It seems this string `2016\2018` in python.

Comment: In [68]: s = s.replace("\\", "'\\'")                                                                                                                                                                                               
In [69]: s                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[69]: '2016\x818'. It's the same thing. Probabaly not an ASCII character.

Comment: Your string have to include second `\\`, change your input string as in my answers.

Comment: 2016\\2018 or 2016\\x818, python will accept this strings as follows: 2016\2018 or 2016\x818

Comment: But like I said, s.replace('\\', "'\\'") doesn't change anyting. I can't manually change my input string. The text is from internet.

Comment: You changed your question after I answered... How are you reading this text? Can you share it too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212313/discussion-between-abigail-min-nm-and-lapestand).